# WCF Multi-Process Handling / Design

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, multiprocessing

I'm currently in the design phase for optimizing one of our WCF-based services.  The service provides wrapper APIs to a set of libraries that are not thread-safe.  The API also takes quite a while to complete (0.5 seconds on average).  There are potentially hundreds of thousands of calls that can happen on a single batch run.

The current endpoint results in disappointing 12-15% CPU utilization (8-core) presumably because there is only one thread to service a call. The libraries not being thread-safe, the only solution it seems is to create multiple processes that each expose an endpoint.

We have to keep the "original" endpoint so the client interface will be the same:

```
Client Thread --> +---------+   +-----------------+ <--> Worker Process 1
Client Thread --> | Service |-->| "Worker Process | <--> Worker Process 2
Client Thread --> | API     |   | Manager"        | <--> Worker Process 3
Client Thread --> +---------+   +-----------------+ <--> Worker Process 4
```

Here are my current thoughts:

1. The original endpoint will forward calls to a "worker process manager"
2. This "manager" will have a pool of threads which in turn make the call to each worker process.  The call is a blocking call.
3. Each worker process exposes an endpoint (almost) identical to each other. (Possibly via named pipes).
4. The original service API will be changed to a per-call instance context (single right now).

This may be a common scenario so I wonder what are the WCF best practices in this case?  If not (unlikely), what's the best way to achieve the best performance given our constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead with the design and was able to achieve 100% CPU utilization. The code needs to be run from a service host (not UI host) to achieve the benefit.

Hope this helps for somebody who run into the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

> The current endpoint results in disappointing 12-15% CPU utilization (8-core) presumably because there is only one thread to service a call.

Just make this clear: WCF easily saturates all CPUs. This limit is imposed by your code.

---

What you propose will work. That said, you can turn on **Web Garden mode** for that IIS application pool. IIS will then spawn multiple processes and distribute requests to them. Hopefully, this request distribution is even enough for you to make it work. If it is not even enough, consider having IIS spawn more worker processes than CPUs.

> This may be a common scenario

First time I have heard about that or saw it on Stack Overflow. Very rare. Basically, you have to work around a misdesigned API here.

Comment: Thanks, but the service is not hosted by IIS (as is our case, which I'm sorry I forgot to mention).  I would prefer NOT to host via IIS, but if that means more scalability, I may give it a try.

Comment: OK, if you self-host, my answer is: Go ahead. This is a sensible approach. Any concrete issues that you see with it?

Comment: I have seen this scenario before when code needed to be called which could run in multiple processes but not multiple threads in a process. An additional case is where the code to be executed automates some desktop-based code that, again, was meant to run in a single process. So, no, it's not common. Most modern code works properly.

Comment: @usr The current host is also used in desktop client scenarios, so running IIS is a bit overkill.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Our scenario is the core libraries we're using are not thread-safe. I know, non-threadsafe libraries should have been extinct by now, but unfortunately not in our case.